# Android Training: Capturing Photo example

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm quite new to android but have been working through the examples on google's site - I'm on this one: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html

This is a "simple" example on using the camera function on android. There is a button that calls up an intent. The intent is displayed below.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch(actionCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;          
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

As you can see above, the intent putExtra of key MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. On android's website: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT it says that the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT has a constant value of "output".

Once the user clicks on a button, the intent is called and the following is an extract of the onActivityResult method given in the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S
```

A method handleSmallCameraPhoto(data); is then called. Here is the code for handleSmallCameraPhoto.

```
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    mVideoUri = null;
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Now in the above method, we want to getExtras from the intent - so what was putExtra in under method dispatchTakePictureIntent we are extracting.

We see this line here.

```
mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Isn't the "data" inside extras.get("data") a key for android to extract the extra data for? From dispatchTakePictureIntent, the key was MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT which had a constant of "output" not "data", how does android know what is associated with "data"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I actually found the answer on the android website. The answer is here: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath under the heading "Get the Thumbnail"

This is a special case and android saves thumbnails with the key called "data" in the intent.

The site says:  This thumbnail image from "data" might be good for an icon, but not a lot more.